# How to know if class object has been deleted in Python

Tags: python, object, python-class

How do I know if an object has been deleted or not in python? I created an object of a certain class and I ran a function of that class inside a while loop. After a few seconds, I deleted the object using `del myObj`. But then this error comes because the object has been deleted and there is no such object anymore.

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myObj' referenced before assignment
```

How do I create a condition or anything else like that without using any external modules to stop calling that method once the object has been deleted? Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Some help: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value and https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python

Comment: `del` **does not delete objects**. It deletes *names*. Python, the language, does not give you any control of when an object is deleted.  CPython the implementation specifically uses reference counting as it's (main) garbage collection strategy. So, `del some_name` will delete a reference, and if the reference count of an object reaches zero, it is immediately reclaimed (although, it is reclaimed to a privately managed heap). Your error has **nothing** to do with an object being deleted. It is telling you the local variable `myObj` is not available in that namespace

Comment: In any case, your description is vague, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do here, you've picked the wrong way to try to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you might be under the common misconception that objects execute code. Objects are not responsible for executing code. When you call a method of an object, it doesn't start doing that while you go off and do something else; instead, the current thread will start executing that method, and return to the call site when the method finishes. That means you can't tell an object to do something, and then delete the object while it's doing the thing to make it stop.